# PHP / MYSQL Echo using the join command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

New to php but learning a lot. Relatively simple question that I believe uses the JOIN command.  In my code...

This gets and prints out the current session user:

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo $userId;
```

But user_id is just a number in my members table, so that will print out "3" or some such. In the same members table, there is a column called 'username' where 3 (id column) is associated with 'Brad' (username column.)

What would the echo command be to get it to print Brad?  I tried something like

```
$actualname = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT members.username JOIN members on userid=members.id"); 

echo $actualname;
```

I don't have a great sense for how the join command functions yet, any help would be great!

Comment: you are missing a FROM clause in your query statement. Can you update your question with the name and structures of your tables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `FROM`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT members.username FROM members WHERE userid= $userId");
```

No need for a `JOIN` here.

Now to display the name:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['username'];
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks very much.  I was confusing the need for join with something else I had attempted a while back.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @slycat see my answer below to understand more about what joins are and how they work so there will not be confusion next time.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a JOIN, as the data is available in the same relational row record and table.

You need to

```
SELECT `username` FROM `members` WHERE `userid` = 3
```

Assuming Brad's userId is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem as already stated is not the `JOIN` but an illegal formed `SELECT` syntax.

> I don't have a great sense for how the join command functions yet, any help would be great!

For starters, here is the [manual link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for the MySQL SELECT syntax which also shows how to use JOIN.

The `JOIN` statement would be used only if you needed to **JOIN** two or more tables together based upon correlating data. For example. If you had another table named addresses and it had a column relating to the members user_id then you could **JOIN** the tables together to get all of the addresses for each user. Example code of JOIN:

```
SELECT
  members.*,
  addresses.*
FROM
  members
  JOIN addresses ON
    members.user_id=addresses.members_user_id
WHERE
  user_id='3'
```

For more examples and to see how different JOINS such as left, right, inner, outer work see this [article explaing sql joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)